# How to detect specific colored objects (red) in image python (without cv2)

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

***Hello folks***,
I am pretty new to image processing in python. I am actually struggeling with simple task. 
I am trying to identify red objects in image with skimage library, not cv2. 
Then I have to count those colored (red in my case) objects in image.

***What I have tried:***
I have tried hsv convertion and creating mask. With this map I created image with only "red" objects.
***Code:***

```
  img_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

  lower_red = np.array([0,70,50])
  upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])
  mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
  mask1 = morphology.erosion(mask1,morphology.disk(3))
  mask1 = morphology.dilation(mask1,morphology.disk(3))

  lower_red = np.array([170,70,50])
  upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])
  mask2 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
  mask2 = morphology.erosion(mask2,morphology.disk(3))
  mask2 = morphology.dilation(mask2,morphology.disk(3))

  mask = mask1 | mask2
  mask = morphology.erosion(mask,morphology.disk(3))
  mask = morphology.dilation(mask,morphology.disk(4))

  output_img = img.copy()
  output_img[np.where(mask==0)] = 0
```

I need something like this but by using skimage library, or by not using cv2 library.

After detecting colored objects I need to count them. I would use *label()* function, but my preprocessing part is not correct so.
Thank you for all your help.

***EDIT*** *06/02/2021 17:31*
Ok guys, I might have found some kind of solution, code below

```
def AntonMlynar(img):
  img_lab = rgb2lab(img)
  img_red = img_lab[:,:,1]
  #plt.hist(img_red.ravel(), bins=256, histtype='bar', color='blue')
  #plt.imshow(img_red)
  mask = img_red>20
  mask = morphology.dilation(mask,morphology.disk(2))
  mask = morphology.erosion(mask,morphology.disk(5))
  mask = morphology.dilation(mask,morphology.disk(3))
  plt.imshow(mask)
  
  labels = label(mask, return_num=True, connectivity=2)
  return labels[1]
```

But I am still not able to count those objects. It need to be dilated to concrete objects.

Comment: Do you have a representative image to share please? What's the objection to **OpenCV** please?

Comment: Yes, it is something like this. https://823018.smushcdn.com/1622763/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/ThinkstockPhotos-636444558.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1

Comment: I could use CIELab color space.

Comment: @antonmlynar if you want to avoid using OpenCV, you can use simple thresholding on the image RGB space by setting a threshold for each channel `R`, `G`, `B`, Red pixels are the ones with high intensity in `R` channel, and low intensity on the other channels `G`, `B`.

Comment: _It need to be dilated to concrete objects._ Then just increase the size of the structuring element in your last `dilation` call, like `.disk(11)` or something like that!?